# Custom HID Keyboard Not Working In Ubuntu

Tags: usb, hid

I have implemented a test HID keyboard using an STM32 microcontroller.

Nothing fanct, just sends continous stream of 'A' once connected at the speed of 10/sec.

Works just fine in windows. But when connected to my Ubuntu 16 machine, nothing shows up even though it gets recognized properly and I see no errors with dmesg

dmesg log:

```
[  +9.163248] usb 2-1.1.2: new full-speed USB device number 34 using ehci-pci
[  +0.110516] usb 2-1.1.2: New USB device found, idVendor=0483, idProduct=5710
[  +0.000005] usb 2-1.1.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[  +0.000003] usb 2-1.1.2: Product: Root Password Unlock Key
[  +0.000002] usb 2-1.1.2: Manufacturer: Nomadic Controls
[  +0.000002] usb 2-1.1.2: SerialNumber: 123456789
[  +0.002741] input: Nomadic Controls Root Password Unlock Key as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.1/2-1.1.2/2-1.1.2:1.0/0003:0483:5710.0012/input/input39
[  +0.059560] hid-generic 0003:0483:5710.0012: input,hidraw2: USB HID v1.00 Keyboard [Nomadic Controls Root Password Unlock Key] on usb-0000:00:1d.0-1.1.2/input0
```

I tested with evtest and I see that the data is coming in fine, just not getting displayed on screen for some reason

evtest log

```
Input device ID: bus 0x3 vendor 0x483 product 0x5710 version 0x100
Input device name: "Nomadic Controls Root Password Unlock Key"
Supported events:
  Event type 0 (EV_SYN)
  Event type 1 (EV_KEY)
    Event code 1 (KEY_ESC)
    Event code 2 (KEY_1)
    Event code 3 (KEY_2)
    Event code 4 (KEY_3)
    Event code 5 (KEY_4)
    Event code 6 (KEY_5)
    Event code 7 (KEY_6)
    Event code 8 (KEY_7)
    Event code 9 (KEY_8)
    Event code 10 (KEY_9)
    Event code 11 (KEY_0)
    Event code 12 (KEY_MINUS)
    Event code 13 (KEY_EQUAL)
    Event code 14 (KEY_BACKSPACE)
    Event code 15 (KEY_TAB)
    Event code 16 (KEY_Q)
    Event code 17 (KEY_W)
    Event code 18 (KEY_E)
    Event code 19 (KEY_R)
    Event code 20 (KEY_T)
    Event code 21 (KEY_Y)
    Event code 22 (KEY_U)
    Event code 23 (KEY_I)
    Event code 24 (KEY_O)
    Event code 25 (KEY_P)
    Event code 26 (KEY_LEFTBRACE)
    Event code 27 (KEY_RIGHTBRACE)
    Event code 28 (KEY_ENTER)
    Event code 29 (KEY_LEFTCTRL)
    Event code 30 (KEY_A)
    Event code 31 (KEY_S)
    Event code 32 (KEY_D)
    Event code 33 (KEY_F)
    Event code 34 (KEY_G)
    Event code 35 (KEY_H)
    Event code 36 (KEY_J)
    Event code 37 (KEY_K)
    Event code 38 (KEY_L)
    Event code 39 (KEY_SEMICOLON)
    Event code 40 (KEY_APOSTROPHE)
    Event code 41 (KEY_GRAVE)
    Event code 42 (KEY_LEFTSHIFT)
    Event code 43 (KEY_BACKSLASH)
    Event code 44 (KEY_Z)
    Event code 45 (KEY_X)
    Event code 46 (KEY_C)
    Event code 47 (KEY_V)
    Event code 48 (KEY_B)
    Event code 49 (KEY_N)
    Event code 50 (KEY_M)
    Event code 51 (KEY_COMMA)
    Event code 52 (KEY_DOT)
    Event code 53 (KEY_SLASH)
    Event code 54 (KEY_RIGHTSHIFT)
    Event code 55 (KEY_KPASTERISK)
    Event code 56 (KEY_LEFTALT)
    Event code 57 (KEY_SPACE)
    Event code 58 (KEY_CAPSLOCK)
    Event code 59 (KEY_F1)
    Event code 60 (KEY_F2)
    Event code 61 (KEY_F3)
    Event code 62 (KEY_F4)
    Event code 63 (KEY_F5)
    Event code 64 (KEY_F6)
    Event code 65 (KEY_F7)
    Event code 66 (KEY_F8)
    Event code 67 (KEY_F9)
    Event code 68 (KEY_F10)
    Event code 69 (KEY_NUMLOCK)
    Event code 70 (KEY_SCROLLLOCK)
    Event code 71 (KEY_KP7)
    Event code 72 (KEY_KP8)
    Event code 73 (KEY_KP9)
    Event code 74 (KEY_KPMINUS)
    Event code 75 (KEY_KP4)
    Event code 76 (KEY_KP5)
    Event code 77 (KEY_KP6)
    Event code 78 (KEY_KPPLUS)
    Event code 79 (KEY_KP1)
    Event code 80 (KEY_KP2)
    Event code 81 (KEY_KP3)
    Event code 82 (KEY_KP0)
    Event code 83 (KEY_KPDOT)
    Event code 86 (KEY_102ND)
    Event code 87 (KEY_F11)
    Event code 88 (KEY_F12)
    Event code 96 (KEY_KPENTER)
    Event code 97 (KEY_RIGHTCTRL)
    Event code 98 (KEY_KPSLASH)
    Event code 99 (KEY_SYSRQ)
    Event code 100 (KEY_RIGHTALT)
    Event code 102 (KEY_HOME)
    Event code 103 (KEY_UP)
    Event code 104 (KEY_PAGEUP)
    Event code 105 (KEY_LEFT)
    Event code 106 (KEY_RIGHT)
    Event code 107 (KEY_END)
    Event code 108 (KEY_DOWN)
    Event code 109 (KEY_PAGEDOWN)
    Event code 110 (KEY_INSERT)
    Event code 111 (KEY_DELETE)
    Event code 119 (KEY_PAUSE)
    Event code 125 (KEY_LEFTMETA)
    Event code 126 (KEY_RIGHTMETA)
    Event code 127 (KEY_COMPOSE)
  Event type 4 (EV_MSC)
    Event code 4 (MSC_SCAN)
  Event type 17 (EV_LED)
    Event code 0 (LED_NUML) state 1
    Event code 1 (LED_CAPSL) state 0
    Event code 2 (LED_SCROLLL) state 0
    Event code 3 (LED_COMPOSE) state 0
    Event code 4 (LED_KANA) state 0
Key repeat handling:
  Repeat type 20 (EV_REP)
    Repeat code 0 (REP_DELAY)
      Value    250
    Repeat code 1 (REP_PERIOD)
      Value     33
Properties:
Testing ... (interrupt to exit)
Event: time 1517685567.317551, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 30 (KEY_A), value 2
Event: time 1517685567.317551, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1517685567.357555, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 30 (KEY_A), value 2
Event: time 1517685567.357555, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1517685567.397568, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 30 (KEY_A), value 2
Event: time 1517685567.397568, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1517685567.421168, type 17 (EV_LED), code 0 (LED_NUML), value 0
Event: time 1517685567.421168, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1517685567.437542, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 30 (KEY_A), value 2
Event: time 1517685567.437542, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1517685567.477549, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 30 (KEY_A), value 2
Event: time 1517685567.477549, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1517685567.517555, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 30 (KEY_A), value 2
Event: time 1517685567.517555, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1517685567.557554, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 30 (KEY_A), value 2
Event: time 1517685567.557554, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1517685567.597552, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 30 (KEY_A), value 2
Event: time 1517685567.597552, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1517685567.637564, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 30 (KEY_A), value 2
```

Any idea what could be happening here?

Answer (score 0):

If `evtest` works, all the involved kernel layers (HID, input) work, so the problem is in the translation of `/dev/input/event*` to X or Wayland (whatever you are running). So for some reason the X `evdev` driver or `libinput` (whatever you are using) don't pick up your HID device.

For X11, look at `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` for clues, and possibly write a custom `xorg.conf` to force inclusion. You can use `xev` to see the X events, and `xinput` to control the X input devices. I can't help you with Wayland.

Comment: Did you mean unsolvable on Wayland?

Comment: @BagasSanjaya: I meant "I don't know enough about Wayland to help you"

Comment: So no one knows about Wayland solution?